# @font-face and chinese characters ... how to?

Tags: css, font-face

At http://goo.gl/NNMZp I found a @font-face kit with chinese characters ... all the needed files and css code are on the server. But I still get latin characters ... 'DHG' > http://www.centrumvoorchinesegeneeswijzen.nl/txp/

What have I to do to get this working?

```
<h1><span>DGH</span><txp:site_name /></h1>

h1 span {
    font: 1em/100% DFXingShuMedium1B;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:'DFXingShuMedium1B';
    src:url('DFXSM1B.eot?') format('eot'),
        url('DFXSM1B.woff') format('woff'),
        url('DFXSM1B.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('DFXSM1B.svg#DFXingShuMedium1B') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

Comment: I also face that problem before but after check it carefully i found that problem is with my font. Did you try any other font?

Comment: @Tarun: see the other comments and answers ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know now it gives to much troubles to have a Chinese font on a (the) server. Most of them are heavy (over 3 MB) and it is impossible to find a generator (Font Squirrel allows only a 2 MB upload) that will make all the necessary files (.ttf,eot,woff,...)

So I'll have to make an image ...

Comment: I did have a look at Google Fonts but although they have a lot of foreign fonts, they don't have Chinese ones ... :(

Comment: What is your target audience? The vast majority of computers have large fonts installed on them these days and can display most languages of the world just fine.